# multiplication for lists in python

Tags: python

I know there is something obvious that I am missing but I would rather clear my confusion than to mug it up. 
why does the following code:
[1]*5
return
[1,1,1,1,1]

and not
[5]

or

[[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]]

Comment: Say you have a list, `l`. Then `3*l` is equivalent to `l + l + l`

Comment: In other words, list addition is equivalent to concatenation. So multiplication is naturally defined in those terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplication is defined for sequences in general, not just `list`s, regardless of the type of the contained values. Sure, `[1] * 5` -> `[5]` makes sense for a `list` of `int`, but it's nonsensical for a `list` of `str`, or a `str` by itself.

They wanted a generic sequence handler that worked for sequences of all types, so they defined it as repeated concatenation, rather than element-wise arithmetic. As juanpa mentions in the comments, this makes for a consistent definition: `seq + seq` is concatenation, so `seq * int` is just `seq + seq` repeated `int` times (well, `seq` is repeated `int` times, with four virtual concatenations), the same way `inta * intb` is just `inta + inta` repeated `intb` times.

If you want element-wise arithmetic, take a look at `numpy` arrays.